# Split regex matches into multiple lines

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I'm using regex to read a line, gather all the matches and print each match as a new line.
So far i have read the line and extracted the data I need but the code prints it all in a single line. 
Is there a way to print each match separately?

Here is the code i have been using:

```
import os
import re

msg = "0,0.000000E+000,NCAP,64Q34,39,39,1028,NCAP,1,1,NCAP"
text = [msg.split(',')]
```

which gives me [['0', '0.000000E+000', 'NCAP', '64Q34', '39', '39', '1028', 'NCAP', '1', '1', 'NCAP']]. 
Searching for data between ' ' will get me the individual results.
Using the code below will find all matches but it keeps it all as one line, giving me the same as the input.

```
text = str(text)
line = text.strip()
m = re.findall("'(.+?)'", line)
found = str(m)
print(found+ '\n')
```

Comment: [`for v in msg.split(','):` => `print(v)`](http://rextester.com/IIBDV53023)

Comment: Also, see [Python: How to separate string with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088442/python-how-to-separate-string-with-comma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what you are trying to capture using regexs, but from what I understand you want to split `msg` up by commas ',' and print each element on a new line.

```
msg = "0,0.000000E+000,NCAP,64Q34,39,39,1028,NCAP,1,1,NCAP"
msg = msg.split(',')
for m in msg:
    print(m)
>>> 0
    0.000000E+000
    NCAP
    ...
```

This will print each element of `msg` on a new line - the elements of `msg` are split up by ','.

I would also use this great online interactive [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) to test your regexs in real time to understand how to use regex / which expressions to use. (make sure to select python language).